# How can I connect lights tight to the underside of a beam?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, junction-box

I have some open beams left exposed for decorative reasons. These beams will have ceiling fan/lights mounted to the bottom of the beams. The wiring will be ran atop the beams in grey PVC conduit, mostly out of sight. Then they reach a makeup box atop the beam (proper grey PVC exposed boxes), and drop through a hole to the light.

I could mount the light directly to the beam, and use the hole itself as a makeup box. This obviously isn't code.

I considered these:

[image]

But if I use something like that, the lights wouldn't be tight against the beam, as these are designed to be sunk into sheetrock.

Is there some code where I could, IDK, wire my wire nuts and encase them in something compact so I could push them back up into the wood hole?

The wood hole is square, about 1.5"x1.5" (I'm not on site to measure, but I think it's a stud width). Plenty of space to contain my wire nuts, and the only thing preventing me from just mummifying them on electrical tape is I know that's against code.

Technically they do have junction boxes. They are just at the top of the beam, six inches away? ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: To be code I think you have to run the wires of the light though the beam in conduit to the junction box and make your connections there.

Comment: @crip659 Exactly. A 6" metal piece of conduit that connects to the light fixture on the bottom and the metal box on top. Don't try this with a plastic box.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Can I use grey pvc electrical conduit?

Comment: You probably could. From a code standpoint, any valid conduit is valid conduit. I just don't like plastic for a bunch of reasons. (I am not anti-plastic for other things, but I am for junction boxes, etc.)

Comment: If the lights/fans are mounted to the beam it should be okay.  Mounted(hanging from) with the PVC is probably not.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I share your distaste of plastic junction boxes. When it comes to conduit, however, I prefer plastic, as an novice, as it's easier for me to work with.

Comment: @crip659 Oh for sure, the fans will be very securely screwed directly to the beam.

Comment: As usual, "it depends": if the light is a fully enclosed fixture (think florescent) it's OK to simply run the  cable thru a knockout, use a cable clamp and make your connection inside the fixture.  What sizes are we working with here....as in the size of the beams?  Would it be possible to route out a recess on the beam so the fixture box sits flush?  Also,  BTW the "fill capacity" of the pancake boxes you showed is extremely limited, basically one cable in  and connections to the fixture wires it all you get, no downstream connections and not larger than 14ga.

Comment: @isherwood  OP ask if they could make connections not in a junction box but in the hole in the wood.

Answer (score 1):

To make the wiring legal, the connection has to be approved for inside the housing of the light (see manual), or in an approved junction box such as the half-depth box you show.

You cannot leave wire connections inside a wooden channel. An inspection will likely not reveal this as a flaw if it's hidden, but an insurance underwriter will want to know why there was an improper connection inside a flammable channel.

The wiring does not need a conduit through the wooden channel.

Your options are to make a connection outside the channel, at either or both ends, or to make the junction inside a legal connector within the channel.

For connections inside the channel you can use an in-line junction box as is available for (buried) outside wiring. It's totally overkill, also considering the cable upgrade needed to exit and enter the junction, but it's legal. Make sure it's installed with sufficient wire slack so that it can be pulled out.

Here's an example, and there are others available at your local store. When purchasing on-line make sure it is UL or cUL as applicable.

[image]

Image: https://www.amazon.ca/ look for Junction-Waterproof-Electrical-Connector-External